spatie/laravel-html - Adding custom data attributes to select options
I'm having problems trying to add custom attributes to select options using spatie/laravel-html. I'm coming over from Laravel Collective which allowed you to just submit a extra attributes collection, eg:
Controller:
$contact_detail_types = ContactDetailType::pluck('contact_detail_type','id')->all();
$option_attributes = collect(ContactDetailType::all())
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
        return [$item->id => ['data-input-mask' => $item->input_mask]];
    })->all();

Blade (Laravel Collective):
{!! Form::select('contact_detail_type_id', $contact_detail_types, null, $option_attributes) !!}

Now with spatie/laravel-html, there is no such extra variable. How do I achieve this?:
{{ 
html()->select('contact_detail_type_id')
   ->children($contact_detail_types, function ($contact_detail_type, $id){
       return html()->option($contact_detail_type, $id)->attribute($cdt_input_masks[$id]);
   })
   ->class('form-control kt-select2' . ($errors->has('contact_detail_type_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '')) 
}}

How would I pass $option_attributes through to the custom ->option call / sub function?

Very unclear what you need help with, please update your question and add additional details. Where is the error happening? What are you trying to achieve?

Apologies @geertjanknapen - I've sorted out the error. Just need help with applying the $option_attributes to the ->children() call

->children($contact_detail_types, function ($contact_detail_type, $id) use ($option_attributes) { might work. Also changing ->attribute() to ->attributes() so you can pass an array or collection.

This was what I came up with for those that need an answer to this:
{{ html()->select('contact_detail_type_id')
    ->children($contact_detail_types, function ($contact_detail_type, $id) use ($option_attributes){
        return html()->option($contact_detail_type, $id)->attribute('data-input-mask', $option_attributes[$id]['data-input-mask']);
    })
    ->class('form-control kt-select2' . ($errors->has('contact_detail_type_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '')) }}

//edit: if you need this to work on an 'edit' page:
return html()->option($contact_detail_type, $id)->attribute('data-input-mask', $option_attributes[$id]['data-input-mask'])->selectedIf($contact_detail->contact_detail_type_id==$id);

